# How to change POM version in CI build?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm probably approaching the problem all wrong, but here goes...

We want to implement a `development` -> `releases/x.y.z` -> `master` workflow using Gitlab and Nexus. The artifacts should be labelled `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT`, `x.y.z-rc` and `x.y.z` respectively.

In the `ci-build.yml`, I have tried to modify the POM depending on the current branch so as to create the correctly labelled artifacts. The problem is obviously that the change will be one commit ahead of the current build commit and the POM used in the build has the original version.

e.g.

- a release branch is created from development
- the POM has 2.3.4-SNAPSHOT and, during the `ci-build`, is modified to 2.3.4-rc and is committed and pushed to git
- the subsequent build and deploy actions are executed but this deploys a 2.3.4-SNAPSHOT package to Nexus and not 2.3.4-rc as wanted

My question here is the following:

**Can I modify the POM and use the updated POM in all following stages of the `ci-build`?**

*(I don't feel that this is the correct procedure, but it is what my team-leader has requested so I'm trying to implement it...)*

Comment: Based on this `x.y.z-SNAPSHOT, x.y.z-rc and x.y.z` you have to do at least two releases technically. I don't understand why people using RC things but that is a different story. Furthermore if you don't commit the change you can not track back the changes. If you like to release an `x.y.z-rc` you have start with `x.y.z-rc-SNAPSHOT` version... no way out of that...

Comment: I don't quite understand why the old POM is used by Maven after you have changed the content of the file. Are you somehow checking out again the old POM?

Comment: @JFabianMeier At the start of each CI stage the following message is displayed: 'Checking out 205a1e8e as master...'. This does suggest that the triggering commit is checked-out at the start of each stage. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution was to avoid commits altogether and use the strategy described in https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html.

This defines a new property, `revision`, which can be set using a maven parameter, `-Drevision=x.y.z-SUFFIX`. The POM version is set from this variable.

The build-ci reads `project/properties/revision` to extract the POM version and alters the version as appropriate depending on the current branch.

Using this approach I can achieve the required results without adding any extra commits as Maven can execute its goals using the version provided externally.